# Why did Denmark, Sweden, and Germany reject a joint investigation offered by Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, germany, sweden, denmark, nord-stream

Why did Denmark, Sweden, and  Germany reject a joint investigation offered by Russia regarding the explosion of the NordStream pipeline?

What are their respective problems?

Comment: Would it be possible to link to some sources about it? Also maybe write a bit more why that is so surprising to you. I would immediately assume security concerns with regards to Russia and would find them plausible. They also sanction Russia for example. But I don't know if these countries said anything about it.

Comment: This was discussed on meta https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/consider-restricting-down-vote/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### There is a debate strategy known as 'bullshitting.'

[Bullshitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandolini%27s_law) relies on the fact that stating a falsehood or half-truth takes considerably less time and energy than refuting that falsehood. So in a structured debate like a panel of experts or the report of a commission, it is fruitless for someone seeking the truth to debate bullshitters unless there is an audience that knows enough to dismiss the bullshit out of hand. And few of the public are going to dive to the pipeline for themselves.

The bullshitter will simply tell a dozen lies in a dozen sentences, and when the side seeking the truth has spent half an hour debunking the first lie, the bullshitter will say *"see, they couldn't answer the other eleven points."*

The EU [has officially stated](https://euvsdisinfo.eu/bullshit-the-noisy-conqueror-of-the-information-space/#) their conclusion that bullshitting is part of the Russian strategy.

The idea that there could be an 'impartial' joint investigation by the two sides appears preposterous. As Russia sees it, the 'West' is fighting a proxy war to destroy Russia. As the 'West' sees it, the Russian government has been lying about plans to start a war of aggression, about war crimes in Ukraine, etc.

Comment: maybe related to [sealioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealioning).

Comment: @wrod, sealioning distracts the opponent speaker, bullshitting distracts the audience. I think this is the latter.

Answer (score 4):

They also do not co-operate with each other, not just with Russia, [citing "national security"](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/sweden-shuns-formal-joint-investigation-nord-stream-leak-citing-national-2022-10-14/) as the reason. It is not very clear where is the threat to the national security here, but:

- It may be secret which kind and how in depth investigation the country is able to do and how conclusions can be derived.
- If the perpetrator is between investigators, there is an opportunity for them to tamper and hide, or, differently, put fake evidences.
- As another answer correctly states, the perpetrator would have possibility to create chaos during investigation and the in final report, by flooding it with the mass of claims that cannot be proven or disproven yet all push in the wanted direction.
- Disclosing the perpetrator may have huge political impact and they may want to have a freedom not to do this if the circumstances are not favorable.

Comment: They may all suspect Russia above all others; inviting representatives of the perpetrator to the investigation offers the perpetrator the chance to make evidence disappear if the investigation closes in.

Comment: The official reason given by Sweden in the article you link to is "confidentiality" not "national security". IIRC their laws prevent investigation from being disclosed too easily.

Comment: Confidenciality is how is done, not why. Replaced the link where it is more directly said

Answer (score -2):

Denmark and Germany are NATO members and Sweden is trying to join NATO. Russia is NATO's enemy. This is already a reason to reject cooperation, especially during a war between NATO+Ukraine and Russia.

Moreover, assuming that the guilty party is not Russian or Russia-affiliated - Russia would have a strong interest in conducting a thorough investigation and reaching conclusions, which would make it difficult if the investigating states were to want to delay, fudge or cook the investigation results for political purposes. Such corruptions of international investigations are not unheard of (e.g. recently in the Douma incident in the OPCW).

We should also note the likely suspect [is the USA](https://seymourhersh.substack.com/p/how-america-took-out-the-nord-stream) - the senior partner in NATO. Obviously, a verification of its guilt would not be politically expedient for it and for the German leadership, nor for the alliance in general. Not to mention the question of whether other NATO states were aware of this going down - which would have both political and possibly legal implications... no no, better to avoid such possibilities by keeping the investigation under control. And for keeping investigations under control you need friendly like-minded organizing parties.

Comment: The most likely suspect is Ukraine itself, due to a number of investigations that have been carried out and are currently being carried out. Of course, that was always the case: Ukraine is the only country that is currently actively fighting a war against Russia, with others only supplying weapons and so forth, so it should naturally have been the first suspect for any attack on Russian infrastructure. There's some evidence that European and US spy agencies may have learned of the plan before it happened, though.

Comment: @Obie2.0: No, it's not the most likely suspect. In terms of capabilities, opportunity, and stated intent - it's the US. As for fighting a war against Russia - The US, and NATO, are doing so by proxy: Ukraine's war is being fought with US/NATO weapons, US/NATO money and partial US/NATO political and military direction. Of course, that does not entirely discount Ukraine as a possible culprit; and it also fits with an aversion for the investigation to succeed.